# Ways to create and rename sheet in excel (ws.title vs wb.create_sheet)

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I am learning openpyxl and have the following code to create an Excel workbook.

In order to rename the sheets, I have the following code:

```
import openpyxl as xl 

wb = xl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active **---- Not sure if this is necessary?**

# Renaming sheets
ws0 = wb.create_sheet('Sheet1', 0)
ws1 = wb.create_sheet('Sheet2', 1)
ws2 = wb.create_sheet('Sheet3', 2)

# To save workbook to a folder, you need to:
# Specify file path
# Add .xlsx so that it will be saved as Excel (openpyxl only supports .xlsx format)

wb.save('filepath/Workbook1.xlsx')
```

This however, will return 4 sheets instead of 3. But when I try the following, I get 3.

```
# Renaming sheets 
ws.title = "Sheet1"
# ws0 = wb.create_sheet('Sheet1', 0)
ws1 = wb.create_sheet('Sheet2', 1)
ws2 = wb.create_sheet('Sheet3', 2)
```

Can someone advise if it is by default `ws.title = "Sheet1"` to name the 1st sheet of any Excel workbook? And also the purpose of `ws = wb.active`, do I need to call the active sheets in Excel before I type in the command to rename the sheets?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can name any sheet pretty much whatever you want. "Sheet" is just the default, in English, from Excel, that we use. Openpyxl has some logic to check for duplicates and append a counter. So, for example, if you set the title of the first sheet to "Feuille" (default for French) and then create a new one called "Feuille", the new sheet will automatically rename it "Feuille1".

`ws = wb.active` is just convenience. For a file created in Excel it will always give you the sheet that was in focus when the file was saved. But, it's also useful when you've just created a new workbook so that you don't have to type `ws = wb["Sheet"]`

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the detailed explanation!
Lets say if i want to rename the very first sheet that Excel workbook creates by default - do i always use the following command? `ws.title = "insert_sheet_name"`

Comment: Yep, it really is as simple as that.